# VBA - check for text or number

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a spreadsheet that a user will fill in specific cells with data/text.

the whole sheet will be locked to prevent one from changing things.

i want as the first cell B4 to always be unlocked and has data entered in, this then unlocks cell B5 for data entry. this will continue on for many more cells.

here is what i have done so far.....

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 

    If IsNumeric(Range("B4:F4")) = True Then 
        Range("B5").Locked = False 
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sadly we are a supporting community and not a "we do your work"-community. What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? Do you have any code you can share with us?

Comment: Yes i understand, just wanted to get some pointers, didnt expect someone to do it for me. here is what i have done so far.....Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If IsNumeric(Range("B4:F4")) = True Then

Range("B5").Locked = False

End If




End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question to post your code. If you have problems with formatting I will edit your question and make it look properly.

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: You are totally right, but sometimes ppl just need a push in the right direction. I wanted to give him a chance to improve as in my opinion a bad is not good, but the opportunity to make it better with some help. I assume that you edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

So... I made an attempt to help you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
Const inputrange As String = "B4:F4"
Const lockrange As String = "B5:F5"
Const lockedworksheet As String = "Tabelle2"

Set insect = Application.Intersect(target, Range(lockrange))
If Not (insect Is Nothing) Then Exit Sub
Worksheets(lockedworksheet).Unprotect
Range(inputrange).Locked = False
Range(lockrange).Locked = True
For Each cell In Range(inputrange)
    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> 0 Then _
        Cells(cell.Row + 1, cell.Column).Locked = False Else _
            Cells(cell.Row + 1, cell.Column).Value = ""
Next cell
Worksheets(lockedworksheet).Protect
End Sub
```

If you need an explanation, just ask.